# Is there a way to have a .bat script copy files and folders from one drive to another?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to copy a file and folder from on my flash drive to the desktop of any computer I plug it into. I am somewhat familiar with the command line and batch scripts but have not used it for doing file manipulation in this way.

I originally wrote a script to test copy it from my flash drive to my desktop, however, the issue is on a new computer I won't always have the same drive letter assigned.

The code I used to test copy everything with known drive letters where the script starts in the folder on my flash drive where what I want to copy is:

```
copy aFile.file C:\Users\*user*\Desktop
```

where *user* is my user folder.

The main issue I am running into right now is copying things from one drive to another where it needs to go into a user profile

cd has the /D switch which specifically specifies to switch drives.
so

```
cd /D %userprofile%\Desktop
```

goes to the active user's Desktop... right where I want it. 
whereas

```
cd %userprofile%\Desktop
```

does nothing because users are on a separate drive.

Is there something similar to /D for copy? The main issue is that drives letters change and user names change. 
User name changes are easy to deal with because I can use %userprofile\Desktop.

If we assumed that copy made use of the same switches as cd (it doesn't) then what I basically want is:

```
copy /D aFile.file %userprofile%\Desktop
```

I am sure I am missing something relatively simple but I didn't see any switches that seemed to be what I need. 
I am also open to using robocopy if that would be easier, but attributes (timestamp, owner, etc) don't matter to me so I didn't think it would benefit me immediately.

Comment: There's no need to be in a specific drive to receive a copied file! `Copy /Y "aFile.file" "%UserProfile%\Desktop"` copies `aFile.file`, located in the current directory, to the `Desktop` directory for the currently logged in user.

Comment: That works when I run it as a single command, but for some reason in a script it does not copy the files. Any ideas as to what may cause that?

Comment: If you have correctly redirected your Desktop directory, it should work, as it should if your original location was then modified to be a junction. Of course the location should be accessible to the system and the user should have sufficient permissions to write to it too. BTW, you only showed copying a file, you cannot copy folders with that command, for that you'd need the very old `XCopy` command, or `RoboCopy` which superseded it.

Comment: What do you think is the current working directory? the batch script container? well, this assumption is wrong; to point to this, use `%~dp0` (e. g.: `cd /D "%~dp0."`)...

Comment: What about `copy /Y /B "%~dp0aFile.file" "%UserProfile%\Desktop\"` according to aschipfl's comment because of current directory can, but must not be the directory containing the batch file? `%~dp0` references folder containing the batch file and this string always ends with a backslash. Then it does not matter what is the current directory for copying the file `aFile.file` stored in directory of batch file to desktop directory of current user.

Answer (score 0):

batch scripts may not be compatible with `cd`
try to make a script that asks two inputs.

```
@echo off
set /p var1="this is the file that will be moved"
set /p var2="this is the destination"
xcopy %var1% %var2%
echo copied!
pause >nul
```

this will ask for two inputs,first input asks for the file,second one is the file copy to